# I am trying to animate an object with a very simple animation but it does not work

Tags: animation

I am not very good at blender but I know the basics.

I am trying to make a simple animation in Blender. I add the keyframes, and play the animation, however, when I play the animation the keyframes between the main keyframes, does not seem to play or happen.

I have searched for this problem, but i could not find any helpful answers to my exact problem.

Edited:
[image]

On the first frame it looks normal, but it is after the first frame that the problem occurs
[image]

On this screenshot, the cube is still at the original place but it is further in the animation. Lastly
[image]

Here the cube has finally moved, but it teleported there instead of "moving" there.

What do I do?

Comment: We're going to need some more details to have an idea of what's going on in your particular case.  Please include some screenshots of what is wrong and maybe an illustration of what you would like to happen.

Answer (score 2):

I think you accidently set your animation to `constant` interpolation([documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/introduction.html#interpolation)).

You can make the cube move(not teleport) by setting interpolation by setting interpolation to linear or bezier. To set the interpolation, select the animation point or points(Diamond shape in timeline), press <kbd>t</kbd> and select `linear` or `bezier`.

[image: Setting animation interpolation to Bezier]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've chosen a *Constant* interpolation instead of *Linear* or *Bezier*, it makes the object jump from position A to B. Open the *Dope Sheet* to check, if I'm correct there will be a green light between the keyframes, which means that the interpolation is constant. Press <kbd>T</kbd> to switch to other interpolation modes, or header menu > *Key > Interpolation Mode*.

[image]

Here is what it gives in the *Graph Editor* (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>) to switch from *Dope Sheet* to *Graph Editor*. As you can see the object will jump from position when keyframed:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked :D